# curl only attempting public key auth for SFTP, not printing SSH authentication methods available

Tags: authentication, sftp, curl

I am trying to use `curl` to connect to an SFTP server. The server only accepts password authentication. When I try to connect, `curl` only attempts public-key auth.

```
$ curl --verbose --insecure 'sftp://exampleuser:examplepass@sftp.example.com:2020/test.txt'
*   Trying 100.100.70.70:2020...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sftp.example.com (100.100.70.70) port 2020 (#0)
* User: exampleuser
* Authentication using SSH public key file
* Authentication failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (67) Authentication failure
```

I have tried many things to force it to use password auth, such as:

```
$ curl --verbose --insecure --user 'exampleuser:examplepass' --key '' --pubkey '' 'sftp://sftp.example.com:2020/test.txt'
*   Trying 100.100.70.70:2020...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sftp.example.com (100.100.70.70) port 2020 (#0)
* User: exampleuser
* Known hosts: /home/example/.ssh/known_hosts
* Could not load public key file
* Authentication using SSH public key file
* Could not load private key file
* Closing connection 0
curl: (67) Could not load public key file
```

I do know that the username and password work. I can successfully use `sftp` to connect to the server.

I find it strange that `curl` is not printing out any message about SSH authentication methods, which I have seen elsewhere. Maybe this is a clue?

```
SSH authentication methods available: password,publickey
```

Is there any way to get `curl` to work in my situation? Or diagnose why it doesn't attempt password auth?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, with `curl` 7.68.0-1, `libssh-4` 0.9.3-2, and `libssl1.1` 1.1.1f-1.